# Unable to access django app from AWS fargate cluster public IP that uses AWS RDS PostGreSQL and dockerized via ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I was trying to create a django app. My django app uses AWS RDS PosGresql. It was then dockerized and tested in local. I am able to get and post records to AWS RDS via local.

Next, I pushed this doker image to ECR. After that created a fargate cluster, a task definition using the ECR repo and ran a task. But, when I tried to access the public IP, page is not working. Logs of the task I ran is showing below.
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGg1b.png)

It appears that fargate is unable to connect to AWS RDS database.

To confirm that AWS RDS is not connecting, I created a simple helloworld django app (without AWS RDS or any other DB), dockerized it, pushed the image to ECR and ran via fargate cluster task. Settings and SG for ECR/fargate used was same. It ran fine. This strengthens my suspicion that somehow fargate is not able to connect with AWS RDS.

Any advises to make this work is appreciated.

My security inbound rules dor fargate cluster SG & AWS RDS SG are as follows. Also listed the docker file used (which worked fine in local with AWS RDS)

[Inbound rules for fargate clusted security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Eyx.png)

[Inbound rules for AWS RDS PostGresql SG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xjs5.png)

[Docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjO2R.png)

Comment: a timeout usually means an issue with security group. make sure that your fargate cluster's security group is added in your RDS security group on port 5432

Comment: Thx for the solution...It worked once I added fargate's SG to my RDS SG on port 5432..